# How to find child name from a value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I need your help. I am developing an IOS app using firebase and swift. I have a list of users in JSON file, using that JSON file I am trying to authenticate user. 
At the moment, my code can retrieve value of email. My goal is to get the ID if I give my Input as email. For examlple: IF i give email as sandeep@gmail.com then I need it ID as 231. For this I have written a function findParent(), but i am getting this error "cannot convert value of type 'UITextfield' to expected argument type 'string'". Please help me.
Below are supplements:

Json File:

```
[
 {
   "ID": 231,
   "iN_Hub Membership": 12345,
   "title": "Mr.",
   "firstname": "kumar",
   "lastname": "sandeep",
   "email": "sandeep@gmail.com",
 },
```

Swift code:

```
  import UIKit
    import Firebase
    import FirebaseAuth
    //import FirebaseDatabase



    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var emailofUser: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var passwordofUser: UITextField!
        var ref:FIRDatabaseReference! //created a variable ref of type firebase database reference
        var databaseHandle:FIRDatabaseHandle? //to handle to database listener like to stop or start it

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


            let newRef = ref.child("4")





            newRef.queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

                    let userId = snapshot.value!["ID"]

                    let memberhipNum = snapshot.value!["iN_Hub Membership"]
                    let emailID = snapshot.value!["email"]
                    print(userId)
                    print(memberhipNum)
                    print(emailID)


            })
            }


        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


        @IBAction func LoginPage(sender: UIButton) {

            func findParent(emailid: String) {

                //set firebase reference
                ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

                ref.child(emailid ).queryOrderedByKey().observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot1 in

                    let myuserID = snapshot1.value!["ID"]

                    print(myuserID)

                })
    }

            findParent(emailofUser)



              if let email = emailofUser.text, pass = passwordofUser.text {




              FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) -> Void in



                if error == nil{
                print("Now its working. Well done Sandeep!!")

               self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UserDetails", sender: self)


                }


                else{

                    print("nonononono")

                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "oops!", message: "user name and password combination is wrong!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

                    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)



                }


            })

            }

    }

    }
```

Hope anyone will help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That question was answered previously with a  code example which illustrates how to query by email and also retrieve the ID value.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake that could be the problem:

```
findParent(emailofUser)
```

Should be:

```
findParent(emailofUser.text)
```